# Replace a regular expression within vim with an output produced by a console command with the expression as its argument?

Tags: linux, vim, find-and-replace

let's say I have a file with the following content:

> This is a _file_ which has some _special_ keywords, that I would
>   _like_ to replace.

I can do a search and replace of the speical keywords with "%s/_*_/something", but I would like "something" to be an output of an external command. Is this possible in vim, or do I need to awk it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can. See `:help sub-replace-special`; the `\=` allows you to replace with a Vim expression. And `system()` can execute an external command and return its output. See my trivial example with `hostname`. Note that I had to use `substitute()` to get rid of the trailing newline character(s) in the output.

```
:%s/_[^_]*_/\=substitute(system('hostname'),'\n','','g')/g
```

<sup>PS: I also corrected your regexp pattern to match your example.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

In Ingos answer, which helped me a lot, I don't see how to reference a subpattern of the match and use it as an argument to the shell command ("produced by a console command with the expression as its argument").

In my case I had log lines of the following form: `[<unix timestamp>] <message>`, i.e. `[1406844000] foobar`. I wanted to prepend them with the time in a human readable form.

The following vim command matches the timestamp (submatch 1) and the message (the rest, submatch 2) and prepends the time string from date command:

```
:% s/^\[\(\d\+\)\] \(.*\)$/\=substitute(system('date -d @'.submatch(1)),'\n', '', 'g').': ['.submatch(1).'] '.submatch(2)/
```

`[1406844000] foobar` gets `Fr 1. Aug 00:00:00 CEST 2014: [1406844000] foobar`.

HTH

Comment: Awesome. Convert basic math to a result, at the touch of a key: `vnoremap <leader>M y:%s/\C\<<C-r>"\>/\=substitute(system('expr '.submatch(0)),'\n','','g')/g` (where math doesn't involve multiplication or division, which would have to be escaped somehow)

Answer (score 2):

For base64 substitution in a ldiff file:

```
:%s/:: \(.*\)$/\=substitute(': ' . system('echo '.submatch(1).'|base64 -d'),'\n','','g')/
```